# LookUpSet - Group By

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I have 2 databases:

Database1 on Server1
Database2 on Server2

I create a table that gives me a small example result below:

```
Name       |  Date        | Total
Name1         10/04/2014    125,101
Name1         11/04/2014    125,101
Name2         10/04/2014    2,5
Name2         11/04/2014    2,5
```

So from Database1 on Server1 I get the Date and Name values.

I get the total column by using the following expression on the 'Total' textbox field that looksup the total from Database2 on Server2:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Col1.Value, Fields!Col1a.Value, Fields!TotalCol.Value, "DataSetServer2"),",")
```

Obviously what I want to do is get the following results:

```
Name       |  Date        | Total
Name1         10/04/2014    125
Name1         11/04/2014    101
Name2         10/04/2014    2
Name2         11/04/2014    5
```

Is this possible? If any further information is needed then let me know, apologies I have never really used LookUpSet.

Additional Info:

DataSet2 is used to query Database1 on Server1 to create the table and example data is:

```
Date        | Col1    | Name
10/04/2014    UID01     Name1
11/04/2014    UID01     Name1
10/04/2014    UID02     Name2
11/04/2014    UID02     Name2
```

The following dataset is then used to query Database2 on Server2

```
Date        | TotalCol   | Col1a
10/04/2014    125          UID01
11/04/2014    101          UID01
10/04/2014    2            UID02
11/04/2014    5            UID02
```

Comment: What do the two underlying datasets look like? Can you add some sample data to the question?

Comment: Have added sample data from the 2 datasets that make up the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your sample datasets:

[image]

[image]

I have created a simple table based on the first dataset:

[image]

The expression is:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Col1.Value & Fields!Date.Value
    , Fields!Col1a.Value & Fields!Date.Value
    , Fields!TotalCol.Value
    , "DataSetServer2")
```

You'll note that I'm comparing `Fields!Col1.Value & Fields!Date.Value` to `Fields!Col1a.Value & Fields!Date.Value` in the first two parameters here. You can pass any expression, it doesn't have to be one column. The expression I've used give the unique lookup comparisons you require.

Since we're getting the unique rows, `LookupSet` can be replaced with `Lookup`.

This gives the required results:

[image]

You just need to find a way to make the lookup unique, i.e. some combination of `Col` and `Date`. You could even use a calculated field in the dataset.

Comment: That's great Ian, thanks so much. I didn't realise you could use a combination like that.